# PHP, preg_match_all, unexpected matches in matching groups using PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have the following regular expression:

```
/(\bafter[\s_:.,()-]+|\bnach[\s_:.,()-]+|\bd'apres[\s_:.,()-]+|\bd´apres[\s_:.,()-]+|\bCircle of[\s_:.,()-]+)*(Pablo[\s_:.,()-]+Picasso|Picasso[\s_:.,()-]+Pablo)([\s_:.,()-]+Nachfolge\b|[\s_:.,()-]+Nachfolger\b|[\s_:.,()-]+Nachfolgerin\b|[\s_:.,()-]+Werkstatt\b|[\s_:.,()-]+Umkreis\b|[\s_:.,()-]+d'apres\b|[\s_:.,()-]+d´apres\b|[\s_:.,()-]+Circle of\b)*/uim
```

Input string: `This is a test Pablo Picasso bla`

I am using `preg_match_all($regex, $input, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)` to get all matches with their offsets.

Result:

```
array(4) {
  [0] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    array(2) {
      [0] =>
      string(13) "Pablo Picasso"
      [1] =>
      int(15)
    }
  }
  [1] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    array(2) {
      [0] =>
      string(0) ""
      [1] =>
      int(-1)
    }
  }
  [2] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    array(2) {
      [0] =>
      string(13) "Pablo Picasso"
      [1] =>
      int(15)
    }
  }
  [3] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(0) "" // why is this type string and no array containing empty string + negative offset (-1) as values?
  }
}
```

Why is `array[3][0]` (third matching group, first match) an empty string and not an array with an offset equally `-1` like in `array[1][0]` first matching group, first match?

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  string(0) ""
  [1] =>
  int(-1)
}
```

There is an array as matching result in this position if I use the following input string: `This is a test after Pablo Picasso (d'apres)` (Because of match `(d'apres`).

See example: https://regex101.com/r/euKHUW/2

Environment:

```
PHP 7.2.12 (cli) (built: Nov 24 2018 18:28:09) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.12, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans
```

Why there is no array containing as first key an empty string and as second key a negative offset (`-1`) if there was no match found for the third matching group, first match?

Comment: It is an optional group at the end of the pattern, it is not shown. You may actually make these optional repeated groups non-capturing and enclose with a capturing group to always get them, see https://regex101.com/r/euKHUW/3

Comment: thats clever! Now i have to keep in mind, that I cannot rely on `-1` as "not found", because first and third matching group matches also "emptyness": Just check if the returned match is an empty string. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an optional group at the end of the pattern, it is not shown.

You may actually make these optional repeated groups non-capturing and enclose with a capturing group to always get them, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/euKHUW/3). Then, all you need is to check if the returned group(s) matched an empty string.

There are other steps you may take to streamline the pattern:

- `\bd'apres[\s_:.,()-]+|\bd´apres[\s_:.,()-]+` can be written as `\bd[´']apres[\s_:.,()-]+`
- `\bafter[\s_:.,()-]+|\bnach[\s_:.,()-]+...` can be written as `\b(?:after|nach)[\s_:.,()-]+`, use inner non-capturing groups and only have repeating patterns once.

See the modified pattern:

```
((?:\b(?:after|nach|d[´']apres|Circle of)[\s_:.,()-]+)*)(Pablo[\s_:.,()-]+Picasso|Picasso[\s_:.,()-]+Pablo)((?:[\s_:.,()-]+(?:(?:Nachfolge(?:r(?:in)?)?|Werkstatt|Umkreis|d['´]apres|Circle of)\b))*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/euKHUW/4)

Comment: Your answer is great! I modified my regex - now it is much cleaner. However, I can not use the part where you optimized the words itself `(?:Nachfolge(?:r(?:in)?)?` as these words come from a database (users can specify them so I need to process them as they are). But thanks to you I learned how to use `?:` :)